Definition of directed graph in Robertson & Seymour's article n°23
I am interested in theorem 1.7 in Robertson and Seymour's article Graph minors XXIII. It states :

Let $\Omega$ be a well-quasi-order. For $i\leq 1$ let $G_i$ be a directed graph, and let $\phi_i : V (G_i ) \cup E(G_i ) \to E(\Omega)$ be
some function. Then there exist $j>i\geq 1$ and a map $\eta$ with domain $V (G_i ) \cup E(G_i )$, satisfying:

for each $v\in V(G_i)$, $\eta(v)$ is a connected subgraph of $G_j$ , and there exists $w \in V(\eta (v))$ with $\phi_i (v) \leq
\phi_j (w)$; and $\eta (v) \cap \eta (v′)$ is null for all distinct $v, v′ \in V (G_i )$;
for each $e \in E(G_i )$, $\eta(e)$ is an edge of $G_j$ , a loop if and only if $e$ is a loop, with $\phi_i (e) \leq \phi_j (\eta (e))$; and
$\eta (e) \neq \eta (e′)$ for all distinct $e, e′ \in E(G_i )$;
for each $e \in E(G_i )$ with head $u$ and tail $v$, $\eta (e)$ has head in $V (\eta (u))$ and tail in $V (\eta (v))$, and $\eta (e)$ is not
an edge of $\eta(u)$ or $\eta(v)$ (the last is trivial unless $u = v$).


My question is the following : with which definition of a directed graph are working ? In the paper, they provide the definition of a hypergraph but not (as far as I could see) the one for a graph. From the formulation of the theorem, theirs seem closer to Wikipedia's definition of a quiver than of a directed graph.
Less importantly, when they mention that $\eta(v)\cap \eta(v')$ is null, do they mean that those do subgraph do not share any edge or any vertices ?

The definition of directed graphs used here allow directed edges of the form $vv$ or self loops. As $\eta{(v)}$ is a subgraph, the fact that $\eta{(v)} \cap \eta{(v')} = \emptyset$ means that those two subgraphs do not intersect. They do not share any edges or vertices.

Thank you ! One last thing : is an edge uniquely defined by its endpoints, as when taking the set of edges as a subset of $V\times V$, or not ?

Yes it is so if and only if multiple edges are not allowed between two vertices then it is uniquely defined by its endpoints, i.e. $u_1v_1$ and $u_2v_2$ represent same edge, then $u_1 = u_2$ and $v_1 = v_2$.  But if multiple edges are allowed between vertices, then $uv$ can be the representation of many edges between the same two vertices $u$ and $v$. For example in the third condition for map $\eta$, "we have for each $e \in E(G_i)$ with head $u$ and tail $v$" they consider possibility of multiple edges between $u$ and $v$.
